# What does "a testing procedure is valid" mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How is "a testing procedure is valid" defined?

For example, in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)

> Fisher's exact test is a statistical significance test used in the
>   analysis of contingency tables. Although in practice it is employed
>   when sample sizes are small, it is **valid** for all sample sizes.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

(Moving my comment to an answer so the question doesn't stay unanswered.)

I don't think the intend the word in a statistically technical sense.

I think they simply mean that the procedure works as a formal test at large sample sizes rather than being exclusively a small-sample test.

There's nothing about the way the test is constructed that assumes a particular sample size.

I suppose you could interpret it to mean something formal -- that they're claiming it has (no more than) the nominal type I error rate -- but I don't think they actually meant that.